# How to get failure cause of qemu-img?

Tags: qemu

qemu-img just quits with error code 1, and no mention of what was the actual problem.

i'm running the very first command from their docs: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/CreateSnapshot#Create_a_snapshot

```
$ qemu-img create  -f qcow2 -b arch-x86.qcow2 snapshot.qcow2
qemu-img: snapshot.qcow2: Backing file specified without backing format
Detected format of qcow2.
$ (exit code of previous command: 1)
```

is the missing parameter the failure? it reads like a warning that it can work around (it even tells which format it is) and then failure is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently that was the failure and those docs are out of date.

If i add the -F parameter it is complaining about, things work.

```
$ qemu-img create  -f qcow2 -b arch-x86.qcow2 -F qcow2 snapshot.qcow2
Formatting 'snapshot.qcow2', fmt=qcow2 cluster_size=65536 extended_l2=off compression_type=zlib size=42949672960 backing_file=arch-x86.qcow2 backing_fmt=qcow2 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
$ (exit code from above is 0)
```